# Case sensitive LIKE

Tags: sqlite

How do rewrite `LIKE "M%"` to match the following:

"MAneany"
"MAree"
"MCrea"

but not these:

"McCrea"
"MacCrea"

I.e. A Capital M followed by a Capital Letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a second character from a string named `last_name`, use `SUBSTR(last_name, 2, 1)`.
To get a hex character code, use `HEX(character)`. In your case you need a character range from "A" (41 hex, 65 dec) to "Z" (5a hex, 90 dec).

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE last_name LIKE "M%"
AND HEX(SUBSTR(last_name, 2, 1)) >= HEX("A")
AND HEX(SUBSTR(last_name, 2, 1)) <= HEX("Z");
```